# How can I flatten a warped board on a picnic table?

Tags: wood, nails, nailing

As seen in picture, one of the pieces of wood is sticking up.  The top panels are secured by nails that go through the perpendicular supports.  I tried hammer the top of this wood panel back into the nail with no success.  Then I tried just hammer up the entire piece so I can remove this nail but the other nails that secure this piece to the perpendicular supports are not budging.  The nails from the bottom are embedded to deep to try to pull out too.  Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the top, looking down. Most likely, you'll need to use a clamp to squeeze the warped board down so it's flush with the board next to it, then drill a new hole and drive a screw to hold it down. Now that this is warped, it may be very difficult to get it to ever lay flat again, though. You may end up having to replace the board entirely.

Comment: can you push it into place momentarily with your hands?

Comment: it pushes down only about 1/4 inch and immediate springs up after releasing pressure

Comment: Ok I was able to get this board out by using a prybar.  Turns out the biggest issue was that the board was very warped and not that it just refused to push into the nail

Answer (score 1):

The chances are you are not unwarping the board.   You can try but its been there a while and will probably go back.   I would hit the really high point with a planer, get it close to even then sand (for a while) this thing flat.   Yes it will take some labor time but the alternative of trying to make this straight will take far longer and probably not work.

Answer (score 0):

Get yourself some 2-1/2" by 5/16" lag screws and washers. Secure the high corner of that board, *and* the diagonally opposing corner.

1. Drill through the sleeper board on the underside with a 5/16" bit.
2. Drill 1" into the underside of the top board with a 3/16" bit.
3. Run the lag screws in and snug them up.

You could also do the job with 2-1/2" deck screws, but you'd have to clamp the board down flat first. Otherwise, the first screw will lock the board into position, which may not be tight, and subsequent screws won't be able to move it further.

Comment: i dont have any heavy duty clamps but i tried with the ones i had and it refuses to push down more than like 1/4 a inch